# How to return an html file as a response python django

Tags: python, django

This is my views file:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def hellothere(request):
    return render(request, "hello.html")  # use forward slashes
```

Everything is right, the name of the file is right, but for some reason django keeps saying that "the template could not be found". What reasons could there be that django couldn't find the template?

This views.py file is in an app called "playground" and the hello.html file is in a folder in playground called "templates". Also, I've already tried adding the filepath to the DIRS attribute in the TEMPLATES array and I've tried using the exact and relative path of hello.html instead of just "hello.html", yet the problem still persists.

Comment: Show us the section of `settings.py` where you configured the template directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was faced with the same problem. I recommend just like.

- Check your settings.py
  First, did you register your app in the installed_apps variables of setting.py?
  Second, can you check the template_dir setting again?
- Could you check your template directory position?

Comment: Shoot I had forgotten to register my app into settings.py... and a regular HTTPresponse return was still working so I didn't think of this... tysm